# Xamarin iOS: Remove old bundle identifiers

Tags: ios, xamarin, certificate, signing

I'm trying to export my Xamarin iOS App from VS. The app includes a Share Extension. Earlier in development, I created another version of my Share Extension "com.cvxtech.ActionBook.ActionBookShare1" which I later deleted in favor of the previous version "com.cvxtech.ActionBook.ActionBookShare." I'm now trying to export the app to the App Store and have correct provisioning for the app and the share extension, but VS is still asking me for a certificate for the previous Share extension (ActionBookShare1). How can I remove the old identifier from my project so that I can export it?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the project, remember to **clean and rebuild** the `solution`. Then Archive again.